# PHP password_hash() / password_verify() and persistent connections

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, password-hash

I am working on a new authentication system for my PHP website, using "password_hash" and "password_verify" functions.

However, many posts recommend using a 'token' system for persistent authentication.

- Is it unsafe to store the password_hash in a Cookie? If yes, why? *(so far as I understand, it is impossible to 'decode' a password hashed with this PHP function)*
- If the previous solution is acceptable, is there any way to compare 2 hashes of the same string? *("password_hash" function will generate a new string every time it is called)*

I would also like to auto-login users when clicking on the "Dashboard" button in my e-mails - through a link like "dashboard.php?email=me@domain.com&pass_hash=XXX"

- Is it unsafe? Why?

Thanks a lot for your enlightened help! :-)

Comment: `password_verify` requires the plain text password and the hash to compare the two. How will you be using the cookie? Should consider the hashing functions timing is to prevent/hinder brute forcing. Why not store the hash in the session...if you were to do that, I dont see a reason to do it though?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the Session expires after few mins/hours. I need the authentication to last for few months. The cookie will be used to re-authenticate the user few days later when he/she visits the website again.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it unsafe to store the password_hash in a Cookie? If yes, why? (so
> far as I understand, it is impossible to 'decode' a password hashed
> with this PHP function)

Yes, it's unsafe. Or at least, less safe than not doing it. If you expose the hash to the user, it enables out-of-band brute forcing. I.e., the user can attack the password offline. In addition, if the password doesn't change often, it allows the contents of the cookie to be copied and authenticated with.

> is there any way to compare 2 hashes of the same string?

You shouldn't ever be directly comparing two hashes to authenticate, you should only be using the return value of `password_verify()`.

If you want to "keep the user logged in", you'd generally authenticate on the first request, start a session, and then use the existence of the session as authentication for subsequent requests. (And then auto-expire the session after some amount of inactivity.)

> I would also like to auto-login users when clicking on the "Dashboard"
> button in my e-mails - through a link like
> "dashboard.php?email=me@domain.com&pass_hash=XXX"
>
> Is it unsafe? Why?

Yes, it's very unsafe. In this design, the hash is essentially no different than the password. Anybody in the world can click the link and they're logged in as the user, without having to know the password. And email can't be guaranteed to be secure, so this design is just as insecure as just emailing somebody a link with the plain password in it.

Anything that automatically logs in is insecure. Just embed a bare link to the target page and have the page make the user log in.

> I need the authentication to last for few months.

This is a code smell. Nobody realistically expects an idle session to last a few months, especially with modern password managers that fill in the authentication for you.